# LMDB modus operandi

Tags: c, database, lmdb

I just started to replace some SQL tables with LMDB, which is a basic key-value store implemented in C ([lmdb link](https://symas.com/lmdb/technical/)).

During the porting, I faced some theoretical questions:

1. The DB uses a cursor instead of a typed key, I assumed it's since the key can be varied according to the requirement (blob), is it so?
2. LMDB maps the databases into memory and it is synced to file only upon transaction commit. How do I maintain integrity in a multi-process environment? Is the memory shared amongst all users?
3. Also, when I tried to remove an item from the DB (using `mdb_del`), it didn't remove it, but just marked it as removed. So it looks like the DB file doesn't ever get smaller, since there's no memory reuse. What's the benefit of this approach?

   Perhaps there's a source that explain in details how it works?

Comment: Lmdb's interesting lockless approach to garbage collecting the database is described briefly in one of the papers linked from the LMDB site. Basically the benefit over immediate reclamation of deleted space is a huge time saving. (I don't know much more than that; I just read the papers you linked to :-) )

Comment: As for point 3, marking stuff as free and not actually releasing it immediately is hardly LMDB's exclusive feature... Pretty much any DB, filesystem and memory allocator will do the same in most cases, recycling items marked as deleted for new data.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks for your comment, I assumed that because the DB file does never get any smaller. Perhaps you can share some insights regarding the second question about how does the DB allow multi-process access without fsync all transaction upon transaction commit. does it hold shared memory with all recent actions ? are they subject to be lost upon sudden reboot (even in this case, the DB is still coherent) ?

Comment: @rici, can you send me a link for this document, I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: @osxUser: the file doesn't get smaller because the pages aren't actually released, but they are recycled for new data whenever they are marked as completely free of valid data *and* new data is added. Also, don't take my word for it (it's a long time since I looked at LMDB), but IIRC the whole DB is just a file mapped in memory between all the processes accessing it. The fact that all processes correctly see the same stuff is guaranteed by the operating system.

Comment: @osxUser: scroll down to the publications section. There are three links labeled "paper", from 2012. There are also pointers to slidesets and videos.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can search by a key "where Key=k". Cursor lets you find the first, last, next or previous key. Cursor also lets you search "where Key>=k". (I found it useful)
2. LMDB supports one writer and many readers. It works for me (Visual Studio using lmdb.v140). The only serverless database I found to be able do that.
3. N/C

Comment: thanks for the help. Perhaps you could clarify one more point regarding the data consistency. I understood that there are 3 modes of operation. one that uses fsync straights upon each transaction, another that uses fsync voluntarily (this improve performance on cost of being able to proper recover from sudden reboot). And a third hybrid mode where the DB fsync the last transaction before another one reaches, this means that in recovery you may lose the last transaction. perhaps you can verify my explanation and let me know how to configure the DB in each of the modes.

Comment: I'm just using the default behavior. I guess it means that fsync happens on each commit. But you can call commit more or less frequently, isn't that similar to "fsync voluntarily"? Finally, if you compare it to a server based database which takes a network RTT on each access, committed or not, I think that LMDB would be much faster even if you commit quite frequently.